# If/Filter clause to query formula (with arrayformula embeded)

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a response sheet on GSheets with over 100 columns/questions that can either be responded by Yes or No. If the candidate answers no they will have to fill in a freetext question.

The following formula - allows me to export the questions that were answered Yes or No from one sheet to another:

```
=QUERY('Module 1 Responses'!$A$2:$AS,"SELECT "&join(",",arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A$1:$W$1,'Module 1 Responses'!$A$1:$AS$1,0),4),1,""))))
```

I would like to add an "if" or a "filter" clause to this formula so that I can only see the "No"s or that would convert all the "Yes" values to blank - if at all possible

Please see sheet with mock data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VBrkVwBa5jXcrQXwB7QGFJhgcbBfjcmCawV7B1YqPcI/edit?usp=sharing

The tab I am working on is called "Action Plan". Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please include an example sheet. It's difficult or impossible to know where the Yes or No fields are nor how everything else is organized.

Comment: Hello @Argyll - thank you for your comment. Please find the sheet with mock details here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VBrkVwBa5jXcrQXwB7QGFJhgcbBfjcmCawV7B1YqPcI/edit?usp=sharing
The tab the formula is on is called "Action Plan".
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the example sheet. Could you clarify what result you want? Verbatim, it sounds like just another layer of `arrayformula(substitute(...,"Yes",""))` in `'Action Plan'!A2`?

Comment: Hello @Argyll thanks for looking into it! Yes, so ideally i would like to see only the no's rather than no's and yes' - so the substitute formula might be the way forward!

Comment: Try it by replacing `...` with your current formula to see if it works or if it's something else that you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE({'Module 1 Responses'!A:C, FILTER('Module 1 Responses'!D:Z, 
 MOD(COLUMN('Module 1 Responses'!D:Z), 2)=0)}, "Yes", ))
```

[image]